# How to get returns for 3,6,12 month using quantmod in R

Tags: r, quantmod

Lets I get data for Apple

```
data = getSymbols('AAPL',from = '2018-01-01',auto.assign = F)
```

How to calculate returns for 3,6,12 month (and any other custom period) using `quantmod` library?

Now I'm using the next code. But it looks ugly

```
  data = getSymbols(symbol,from = '2018-01-01',auto.assign = F)
  data <- to.monthly(data)
  l <-length(data[,1])
  returns = quarterlyReturn(data, type = 'log')
  p3mprofit = (as.numeric(data[l,'data.Adjusted'])-as.numeric(data[l-3,'data.Adjusted']))/as.numeric(data[l-3,'data.Adjusted'])
```

Comment: Please define "returns"? Also: can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @PavoDive returns means profit for period. Also added some code